# centering visual content using un-ordered list (with a fluid-responsive layout)

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists

the visual elements (the rectangles) keep drifting to the left. How can you center these rectangles (they are list UL list items) so they sit symetricly under the header & w/out using absolute units

Want the list elements to be centered under the header like this http://uploadpie.com/7BJuH http://jsfiddle.net/Aarondv1/vmmsfhax/

```css
/* * {border: 1px solid blue;
}
 */
.headercontainer {
 
 border: 1px solid blue;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.bragbanner {
 
 text-align: center;
}


div img {
 max-width: 144px;
 max-height: 35px;
 
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
 filter: grayscale(1);
}
.mainarea {
 
 /* text-align: center;
 
 width: 65%;
 
 border: 1px dotted orange;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 
 overflow: hidden;
 
 padding-left: auto;
 padding-right: auto; */
 
 
 max-width: 940px;   /*What's the significance of 940px? */
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 5%;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

ul li {
 
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
 margin: 2.5%;
 max-width: 45%;
 float: left;
 
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<header class="headercontainer">
<p>30 years experience in Metro-Detroit law</p>
<h1>M</h1>

</header>

<!-- bRAG POINTS
<div class="bragbanner">
<img src="lawyers_logo.png">
<img src="avvo_logo.png">
<img src="legalnews_logo.png">
<img src="aba.jpg">
<img src="free-press.jpg"> -->
</div>

<div class="mainarea">



 
  <ul>
  <li><h3>Family Law</h3></li>
  <li><h3>Domestic Law</h3></li>
  
 
 
 
  <li><h3>Matrimonial Law</h3></li>
  <li><h3>Probate Law</h3></li>
  </ul>
 
 
 
 

</div>


<footer></footer>
</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this CSS with your current CSS and it will work.
CSS:

```
/* * {

    border: 1px solid blue;
}
 */


.headercontainer {

    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;


}


.bragbanner {

    text-align: center;
}


div img {
    max-width: 144px;
    max-height: 35px;

    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);



}


.mainarea {

    /* text-align: center;

    width: 65%;

    border: 1px dotted orange;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    overflow: hidden;

    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto; */


    max-width: 940px;   /*What's the significance of 940px? */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    text-align:center;



}

ul {


    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;

}

ul li {

    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 2.5%;
    max-width: 45%;
    display:inline-block;


}
```

I have given 100% width to `<ul>` and cleared float on `<li>` and added `display:inline-block` to them

Thats it :)